# How to replace version number in file?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I'd like to replace the version number in the pkg-ref lines of my xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <pkg-ref id="com.mycomp.pkg.foo1" version="1.1.15" auth="Root" installKBytes="">#foo1.pkg</pkg-ref>
  <pkg-ref id="com.mycomp.pkg.foo2" version="1.1.15" auth="Root" installKBytes="">#foo2.pkg</pkg-ref>
```

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh

NEW_VERSION="1.2.0"

sed -ie "s/version=\"*.*.*\"/version=\"$NEW_VERSION\"/" foo.xml
```

...but it removes part of the rest of the line and also replaces the xml version which is only 2 digits and which I don't want...leaving me with this:

```
<?xml version="1.2.0"?>
  <pkg-ref id="com.mycomp.pkg.foo1" version="1.2.0">#foo1.pkg</pkg-ref>
  <pkg-ref id="com.mycomp.pkg.foo2" version="1.2.0">#foo2.pkg</pkg-ref>
```

What should my sed line be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use restrictive regular expressions using negated character classes:

```
sed -ie "s/\(<pkg-ref [^>]*version=\"\)[^\"]*\"/\1$NEW_VERSION\"/" foo.xml
```

Breakdown:

- `\(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `<pkg-ref□` Match `<pkg-ref□` literally, `□` denotes a space character
  - `[^>]*` Up to first closing `>`
  - `version=\"` Match `version="` literally (possible backtracks here)
- `\)` End of CG #1
- `[^\"]*\"` Match up to and including first double quotation mark

In replacement string `\1` is a back-reference to first capturing group.

Comment: Wow. That works perfectly. I'd be lying if I said I understood it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed -i "s/version=\"[^\"]*\"/version=\"${NEW_VERSION}\"/g" foo.xml
```

Comment: Then must likely you have BSDs sed. So try `sed -i ''` instead of `sed -i`. Alternatively do `sed -ie` which will create a back up with `e` as extension

Comment: I used sed -ie and it almost worked...the problem being that it also replaced the xml version line which I wanted untouched.